# ${\bf E}[Y]$ of a joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

So, I have that a joint probability density function is given by the formula: 
$$
5e^{-5x} / x, \quad  0 < y < x < \infty
$$
 and I have to find the $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.

I know that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = {\bf E}[XY] - {\bf E}[X]{\bf E}[Y]$. I've been able to find 
${\bf E}[XY]$ and ${\bf E}[X] $ ($1/25$ and $1/5$ respectively, hopefully I'm correct there), but I've been unable to find the ${\bf E}[Y]$... Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[Y]=\int_0^\infty \int_0^x y\cdot \frac{5}{x}e^{-5x} dy dx$. This formula is obtained after inserting into general form $E[Y]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} y \cdot pdf(x,y) dydx$.

Comment: Of course... I kept trying to do dxdy, since I had done the other two that way. Thank you so much!